# predicting argument of quadratic curves svg

Tags: javascript, parsing, svg, path

I am working on project in chrome making cartoon result more curvy 
I just smoothed svg curves and  added Quadratic curves to smooth the curve and and I removed some segments to make it smoother.

but now I am trying to edit the d attribute it wont work and throw error because of  the segment **Q 534.3124322052275 25.9967458509216**
how can i expect the the third and fourth argument of the segment?

```
<path id="facep2" d="M 517.5340151904196 9.20409114251785 M 516.088199322423 17.673568880373665 Q 514.6423834544263 26.143046618229484 509.93922571596306 31.83545533161494 Q 505.2360679774998 37.5278640450004 455.0142118061208 48.02032690276528 Q 404.7923556347418 58.51278976053015 390.5363920270104 61.96132602716666 Q 376.28042841927896 65.40986229380319 358.09676706638334 68.8988173245509 Q 339.91310571348777 72.38777235529862 322.4562212833001 78.95165284114722 Q 304.99933685311254 85.51553332699582 264.43489590376265 135.70972919458012 Q 223.87045495441276 185.9039250621644 219.8903181027034 267.952096989082 Q 215.91018125099401 350.00026891599964 219.52265819306456 367.90553986340524 Q 223.13513513513513 385.8108108108108 224.68560155631747 394.6693374279056 Q 226.23606797749977 403.52786404500046 234.14996772652788 431.681654922211 Q 242.06386747555598 459.8354457994215 243.52222407562346 471.96627121048346 Q 244.98058067569093 484.0970966215454 246.0095956460613 486.35863514724576 Q 247.03861061643167 488.62017367294607 258.76722332415613 504.3160987871389 Q 270.4958360318806 520.0120239013318 283.58024989501666 534.594032912532 Q 296.66466375815276 549.1760419237323 361.83266345252014 588.3457876253641 Q 427.00066314688746 627.5155333269959 451.927904071572 624.7539175465115 Q 476.8551449962566 621.992301766027 494.14143223162085 614.6896286554876 Q 511.4277194669851 607.3869555449481 548.7648669481187 562.7313965526243 Q 586.1020144292522 518.0758375603006 598.3428638307028 502.37601657621525 Q 610.5837132321533 486.67619559212994 615.7758409289613 473.8203252592374 Q 620.9679686257693 460.9644549263448 623.4839843128847 453.4822274631724 Q 626 446 628.2076136996343 442.4913643956122 Q 630.4152273992687 438.98272879122436 631.4746212948442 428.88931882435327 Q 632.5340151904196 418.7959088574822 636.3802571046467 407.47808016458566 Q 640.2264990188738 396.16025147168915 639.597958846121 393.8562045510317 Q 638.9694186733681 391.5521576303742 635.4191726714566 397.3141199181423 Q 631.8689266695451 403.0760822059103 627.4790172146023 400.50383695001125 Q 623.0891077596596 397.93159169411217 627.0285413901905 391.9442050061249 Q 630.9679750207215 385.95681831813766 635.1099023676975 376.240489086889 Q 639.2518297146735 366.52415985564033 639.6043237016222 347.69798714438923 Q 639.9568176885708 328.8718144331381 637.3114134464408 283.92851076506565 Q 634.6660092043109 238.98520709699312 625.0234340271647 215.02182483889754 Q 615.3808588500185 191.058442580802 609.8345919911568 163.00150705771304 Q 604.2883251322951 134.9445715346241 573.8445091658541 107.19196609211237 Q 543.4006931994131 79.43936064960064 538.4097771846644 71.59138856992661 Q 533.4188611699158 63.74341649025258 533.8656466875716 44.87008117058713 Q 534.3124322052275 25.99674585092168 534.3124322052275 25.99674585092168 Q 534.3124322052275 25.99674585092168 Q 517.5340151904196 9.20409114251785 516.088199322423 17.673568880373665 Z " fill="none" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#ff0066" stroke-width="4"></path>
```

[image]

Comment: Per https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataQuadraticBezierCommands Q requires a minimum of 4 arguments. Firefox also requires this (https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/svg/SVGPathDataParser.cpp#276) so I don't know why you think that "works correctly"

Comment: it doesn't throw an error in Firfox I just added the function I used is there any idea to prevent these kind of errors

Comment: It should log an error in the console I believe.